# Trying to use Zend Escaper from ZF 2.1 in Zend Framework 1.11.11

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to use the Zend Escaper class from Zend Framework 2.2 in Zend Framework 1.11.11 by copying the Escaper folder from the ZF 2.2 into ZF 1.11.11. I am trying to do this becuase in the Zend Escaper class documentation it says that the class is a stand-alone class and is not dependent on any of the other Zend classes/interfaces.

But once I added the folder into our ZF 1.11.11 library and tried instantiating the Zend Escaper class and load the web page all I am seeing is an empty page. I am unable to debug this. I tried to print the object that is returned on instanitation using print_r but that did not work.

Our application is built on ZF 1.11.11, switching to ZF 2.2 is a huge risk for us and would be a major change to our application. That is why I am trying to do this.

Please help me know whether it is possible to make Zend Escaper class work in ZF 1.11.11 in the way I am trying to do. If so, why am I getting this problem.

Also, is there any class in ZF 1.11.11 that I could use for encoding/escaping.

Comment: What's showing in the logs?

Comment: Don't try and copy ZF2 code *into* the ZF1 folder. Install Zend Escaper via. composer, then you shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: Fixed the problem by including the file before instantiating it.