# how to "escape" the output zf1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How "escape" the output of a string so js on the search line will not work? In Zend Framework1(v. 1.12.3).

```
    <div id="search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->languageText('TEXT_SEARCH_OUR_SITE',"Search Our Site"); ?>" name="query" id="query" />
        <div class="search-box-bk"></div>
    </div>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
placeholder="<?php echo $this->escape($this->languageText('TEXT_SEARCH_OUR_SITE',"Search Our Site"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Zend 1 does not have good escaping mechanism by default. `->escape()` only uses standard PHP method `htmlspecialchars`.

You can set what escape method to use in Controller by getting View and using method `setEscape('htmlentities')` ( `setEscape(array('Class/Object','method))`)

---

(*response for comment*)

In one of my projects I've used Zend2 Escaper. First I've copied Escaper to my folder in Library (i renamed it to Adx_Escaper so it fits in existing library - I'm lazy ;)). Next I've created ViewHelper (`resources.view.helperPath.Adx_View_Helper = "Adx/View/Helper/"`(application.ini)) with content like this:

```
class Adx_View_Helper_Escaper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
  protected $escaper = null;

  public function Escaper()
  {
    if ($this->escaper === null) {
        $this->escaper = new Adx_Escaper();
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function html($string)
  {
    return $this->escaper->escapeHtml($string);
  }
/* ... */
```

Then i could just use `$this->escaper()->html('SomeText')` (now I see it would be even simpler to just return Escaper in constructor, but works eiter way).

Comment: Thank you.  In my task, `->escape()` didn't work. I thought a lot, and idea came to use `Zend\Escaper` from `Zend Framework 2`. Googling, came across that I was not the only one thinking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534449/trying-to-use-zend-escaper-from-zf-2-1-in-zend-framework-1-11 -eleven
Now I'll think over your words, while thinking about `Zend\Escaper"`. What do you think about integration of `Zend\Escaper` in ZF1 ?

Comment: @AgentSmith I've used Zend2 Escaper in one of my projects. Example added in answer. Maybe will be useful ;)